# Oracle Apex Checkbox Group Limit

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

This might be a silly one but haven't been able to figure it out.
I have a Checkbox Group Item (with Static info) with 4 different options, I want to limit the amount of checked boxes to just two. Is this something possible to make?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A checkbox is submitted as a colon-separated string. `APEX_STRING` has lots of functionality to convert the string to a pl/sql collection (and back). Once converted you can use functions like `FIRST`, `LAST`, `COUNT`. Or even compare collections using `INTERSECT`. For checking a max nr, a `COUNT` is enough.

So the validation would be something like this (type Function Body returning Error Text):

```
DECLARE
  l_arr apex_t_varchar2;
BEGIN
  l_arr := apex_string.split(:P13_CHECKBOX,':');
  IF l_arr.COUNT > 2 THEN 
    RETURN 'Can only select 2 values';
  ELSE
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
END;
```